# ListView with dynamic number of EditTexts containning rows

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

We are having a spring web application for our canteen. 
I am trying to develop an android app in that users will be able to see all the items and put their quantity in front of item name using editText.

I am able to get response as  List using REST to get all the items and show to listView. 
But I find difficulties to put editText in front of all items in listView because number of items are dynamic.

How to create dynamic editText and put them in a listView along with item names received using REST and stored in a List

Comment: the fact you got the list from REST or not doesnt really matter, removed the REST tag from OQ.

Comment: I don't see the problem, logically you just need to create a listadapter with items size you are getting from the rest command. you can still use a listview as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` with `EditTexts` is bad combination, In my case i had to migrate to dynamically filled vertical `LinearLayout` in conjuction with `ScrollView` so that the `EditTexts` behave and they really did. If the size of your List is not too big and your views are not too complicated you should do the same. Otherwise, i would try migrating to `RecyclerView` and see how `EditTexts` would behave then, i cant tell if they would as i havent tried doing so yet.

see [ScrollView+LinearLayout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837983/how-to-make-the-linearlayout-in-scrollview-to-fill-the-whole-area)

and see [add Views to LinearLayout programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically)

and [Inflating views from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123159/how-to-inflate-view-from-xml-in-android)

Comment: Hi Ofek Ron, I am very new in android development so please give me some idea about LinearLayout with example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As Ofek stated in his answer the most appropriate way to do this is with recyclerView and a custom adapter.

First you need a layout for a single item in your list like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_edittext"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_label"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Next you have to create the adapter which handles the data and also listens for changes of text and focus:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

public static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";
private List<String> labels;

public CustomAdapter(List<String> labels) {
    this.labels = labels;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return labels.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    customViewHolder.label.setText(this.labels.get(i));
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    //inflate layout and create new ViewHolder
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.custom_item_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}

//the viewHolder handles the single items in recylerview
public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView label;
    protected EditText editText;

    public CustomViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        label =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        editText = (EditText)  v.findViewById(R.id.item_edittext);

        //listen for changes in your editText
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.d(TAG, s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        //listen for focusChangeEvents
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override

            //at this point may save changed data
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(! hasFocus) {
                    Log.d(TAG, getAdapterPosition()+" has lost focus ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

In your activity use it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
labels.add("label1");
labels.add("label2");
labels.add("label3");
labels.add("label4");
labels.add("label5");


RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(labels);
recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```